# google speech async audio longer than 15 mins return error 500

Tags: google-speech-api

I'm using the google speech apps with the app engine and i'm always getting this error 500. When my recording is over 15 mins (approximatly). Based on the google Doc I should be able to send recording up to 180 mins for asynchronus recording.

> Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

I tried different encodings, but they all have give me the same error. I also made sure to upload my recording on google storage and i'm using the gs address.

This function below is what i'm using. It the function provided in google Doc. I have no clue why long recording crash. i Putted in comment the Thread.sleep(10000) because if the recording was long i was aleays getting a thread sleep interuption.

```
 public static void asyncRecognizeGcs(String gcsUri) throws Exception, IOException {
  // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create();
  long seconds = 0;
  long minutes = 0;

  // Configure remote file request for Linear16
  RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
      .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
      .setLanguageCode("en-US")  /*en-US*/ /*fr-CA*/
      .setSampleRateHertz(44100)
      .setEnableWordTimeOffsets(true)
      .build();
  RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
      .setUri(gcsUri)
      .build();

  // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
  OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
      speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
  while (!response.isDone()) {
    System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
    /*Thread.sleep(10000);*/
  }

  List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();

  for (SpeechRecognitionResult result: results) {
    // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
    // first (most likely) one here.
    for (int i=0; i<result.getAlternativesCount();i++){
        seconds = result.getAlternativesList().get(i).getWordsList().get(0).getStartTimeOrBuilder().getSeconds();
        minutes = (int) (seconds / 60.0);
        HelloAppEngine.textTransalated = HelloAppEngine.textTransalated + "\r\n[" + minutes + "m et " + (seconds % 60) + "s][" + result.getAlternativesList().get(i).getConfidence() + "] " + result.getAlternativesList().get(i).getTranscript();
    }

     /*SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
    System.out.printf("Transcription: %s\n",alternative.getTranscript());
    HelloAppEngine.textTransalated = alternative.getTranscript();*/
  }
  speech.close();
}
```